# PayPal Laravel integration not working due to method not being found

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am using '**"anouar/paypalpayment": ">=3.0"** ' library for PayPal integration with Laravel 5.5 app, but when I traverse any route of payment it shows error

> "Method [showLoginForm] does not exist on [App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController]."

Below is the controller function code which is causing this error:

```
    $shippingAddress= Paypalpayment::shippingAddress();
    $shippingAddress->setLine1("3909 Witmer Road")
        ->setLine2("Niagara Falls")
        ->setCity("Niagara Falls")
        ->setState("NY")
        ->setPostalCode("14305")
        ->setCountryCode("US")
     

 
    $payer = Paypalpayment::payer();
    $payer->setPaymentMethod("paypal");

    $item1 = Paypalpayment::item();
    $item1->setName('Ground Coffee 40 oz')
            ->setDescription('Ground Coffee 40 oz')
            ->setCurrency('USD')
            ->setQuantity(1)
            ->setTax(0.3)
            ->setPrice(7.50);




    $itemList = Paypalpayment::itemList();
    $itemList->setItems([$item1])
        ->setShippingAddress($shippingAddress);


    $details = Paypalpayment::details();
    $details->setShipping("1.2")
            ->setTax("1.3")
            //total of items prices
            ->setSubtotal("17.5");

  
    $amount = Paypalpayment::amount();
    $amount->setCurrency("USD")
           
            ->setTotal("20")
            ->setDetails($details);



    $transaction = Paypalpayment::transaction();
    $transaction->setAmount($amount)
        ->setItemList($itemList)
        ->setDescription("Payment description")
        ->setInvoiceNumber(uniqid());



    $redirectUrls = Paypalpayment::redirectUrls();
    $redirectUrls->setReturnUrl(url("/payments/success"))
        ->setCancelUrl(url("/payments/fails"));

    $payment = Paypalpayment::payment();

    $payment->setIntent("sale")
        ->setPayer($payer)
        ->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls)
        ->setTransactions([$transaction]);


    return response()->json([$payment->toArray(), 'approval_url' => $payment->getApprovalLink()], 200);
```

Comment: Please, show a snippet of your code that reproduces the error you're getting.

Comment: i just added the function code kindly check that